# Xamarin Forms: How to switch images without "flicker"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[I found this question asked once before on SO about a year ago on but it went unanswered so I am asking again (wasn't sure whether best practice was to create a new question or "bump" the existing one).]

I have a Xamarin Forms application which is receiving a stream of JPEGs over HTTP and I want to keep updating a single Image placeholder with their contents.  The frame rate at which I receive the images is very slow by design (maybe 5 fps at most) as this is for a time-lapse photography project.  I want to be able to show the stills as an animation (think: taking a photo of a plant once per hour and then "playing" all of the stills to create a lively animation of said plant).

The problem I am having is with "flicker" while swapping one image out for the next.  I've tried a variety of approaches, including having two Images (one visible at a time) and only changing the visibility once I'm done loading the latest image (I think this is maybe a naive form of double-buffering?).  Have also looked into Motion JPEG, HTTP Keep-Alive, and even using a WebView (I have a valid Motion JPEG endpoint that I can read from). Anyway, nothing that I've found so far has helped reduce the flicker and therefore the "animation" of the stills remains very "jerky" for lack of a better way to put it, with a momentary blank (white) pane between stills.  Frankly speaking, it looks like crap.

Here is the gist of the code which fetches the next "frame" and updates the "player" image:

```
        var url = $"{API_BASE_URL}/{SET_ID}/{_filenames[_currentFilenameIndex]}";
        var imageBytes = await Task.Run(() => _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url));
        var imageBytesStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

        var timeComponents = _filenames[_currentFilenameIndex].Split('T')[1].Split('.')[0].Split('-');
        var timeText = $"{timeComponents[0]}:{timeComponents[1]}:{timeComponents[2]}";

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            () =>
            {
                TimePlaceholder.Text = $"{timeText} (Image {_currentFilenameIndex + 1}/{_filenames.Count})";
                ImagePlaceholder.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageBytesStream);
            });
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: n your current code flow, you have 200ms to download a file, create a memory stream, initialize it with the bytes received, context switch to the ui thread, create an ImageSource from that new stream, apply it to the ImageView and then have Xamarin take that image source and convert it to its native implementation.

Comment: And we have not even mentioned what is the transfer time and size of those jpegs and their native display resolution vs. the actual current display resolution of the ImageView, not to mention that the Forms’  ImageView/ImageSource is just poorly designed for this flipper-style image use-case. If you have a valid M-JPEG source, use it (and have the server convert the resolution to what the device is actually using)

Comment: The delay doesn't affect the flicker.  Very small delay, very large delay, no difference.  Also, even if the JPEG was 10 MB (they're actually about 150 KB each), shouldn't I be able to still do a flicker-free image switch once the new image is fully downloaded?

Comment: In fact, I'd be willing to bet that the flicker would still exist if I were simply switching between two images already on the local filesystem (FileStream, etc) but I haven't technically tried that yet.

Comment: Totally agree, within the same UI control where you are flipping the image via Xamarin's ImageView/ImageSource, just a plain no without flicker...

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. What do you suggest then? I'm a bit new to GUI programming and dealing with optimizations like this.

Comment: Using something as simple as ffmpeg/ffserver to stream M-JPEG (via a secure NGINX proxy to native controls on iOS/Android (via Xamarin-based apps) works really well (I done camera streaming for a few projects). On iOS, using a URLSessionDataTask you can make use of the fact that MJPEG over HTTP is handled via `multipart/x-mixed-replace` and the stream is kept open and you will receive a callback on receipt of each "data" section (i.e. a jpeg), simple to UIImage  that and update a UIImageView (smooth as butter if you use CoreAnimation to "flip" the images at the preferred FPS as received).

Comment: Android is basically the same process but there are 3rd-party OSS Java-based image views available that handle the image buffering(flipping) so you do not have to code that part yourself. The big issue I’ve had on Xamarin.Android is the HttpClient/AndroidClientHandler implementation has ***really*** poor performance and memory handling in the `multipart/x-mixed-replace` use-cases, so much so that I would recommend using “anything else, just anything else" (OkHttp/Volley/etc.. work really well, or hand-code it..)

Comment: Of course, you can always use an embedded WebView if it can fit your use-case (you mentioned it in your question, but what was its issue?)

Comment: The WebView seemed to work well, except that I couldn't get it to fit on the screen. It was HUGE. I tried a variety of layouts but all to no avail. By the way, the images are 1600x1200 JPEGs in case that's relevant.

Comment: 1600x1200 Yes, those can be a problem depending upon the device, as a side note, if the view that you are placing them into is smaller, you really need them to match that size for optimal performance. `WebView...I couldn't get it to fit on the screen` : I would ask another SO question on this (include the HTML content being used)

Comment: Will do. I'm also going to look into some of the other suggestions you made above. Do you want to answer this question more formally so that I can accept your answer? Up to you, but thank you either way as you've been a huge help.